# Deserialize into a list inside the deserialized class?

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, deserialization

Small sample:

```
<head>
    <coordinate>
    ...
    </coordinate>

    <coordinate>
    ...
    </coordinate>

    <coordinate>
    ...
    </coordinate>

    <coordinate>
    ...
    </coordinate>
    etc.
</head>
```

This should result in:

```
public class Head
{
    public coordinate[] coordinates;
}
```

Does the deserialization of the first code sample result in the second code sample after casting the object to the type "Head" ?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Head));
    TextReader reader = new StreamReader("file.xml");
    Head obj = (Head)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add your deserialize code?

Comment: It's a rather big project so I just want to be 100% certain that it is possible to deserialize to an array inside the deserialised class. Serialization is, unfortunately, something I missed out on in the few years I've been programming.

Comment: @Solrik my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29471671/468718) helped ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deserialize your given xml, having flat sequence of `coordinate` xml element, by following way.

Your Sample XML:

```
<head>
    <coordinate>
    ...
    </coordinate>

    <coordinate>
    ...
    </coordinate>

    <coordinate>
    ...
    </coordinate>

    <coordinate>
    ...
    </coordinate>
    etc.
</head>
```

Model Class:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "head")]
public class Head
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "coordinate")]
    public coordinate[] coordinates;
}
```

With above Model class deserializing to `Head` should work with below code of yours..

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Head));
    TextReader reader = new StreamReader("file.xml");
    Head obj = (Head)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
    reader.Close();
}
```

What I have done is decorate `coordinates` property with `[XmlElement]` attribute. So you just need to modify your Model class as above to map properly with given xml sample. More examples you can find at below reference link on msdn.

Reference: [MSDN - Serializing an Array as a Sequence of Elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2baksw0z(v=vs.100).aspx#sectionSection3)

Answer (score 0):

The serialization for the class

```
public class Head
{
   public coordinate[] coordinates;
}
```

is

```
<Head>
  <coordinates>
     <coordinate />
     <coordinate />
     ...
  </coordinates>     
</Head>
```

but, if you want to deserialize your example 1 into a class you can use this class template:

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "head")]
    public class Head
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public coordinate coordinates { get; set; }
    }
    public class coordinate { }
```